# user policy update times out

Tags: windows, group-policy

I have 1 client on my network that wont update user policy. It hangs forever on boot when it has access to the DCs.

Disconnecting it from the network so I can login to it I can update computer policy no problem `gpupdate /force /target:computer` but user policy hangs for 10-15 minutes and then quits with the error `User Policy Refresh has not completed in the expected time. Exiting...`

I used `gplogview.exe -m` to watch the update and **nothing** happens I don't get a single message logged there from start until it times out.

Nothing appears in Event Viewer that I can see.

I'm a bit stumped has anyone come across an issue like this before?

Comment: What is this computer using for DNS?

Comment: The 2 dcs as given by dhcp to everything else as well